# Pandas: is there a method to order columns like in R?

Tags: python, pandas

R's `tidyverse` offers the function `relocate()` to move columns from in specific positions (e.g., `df %>% relocate("col1", .after="col2"`). Is there a way to do this in Python Pandas, even better with a method?

Comment: There are `pop` and `insert` methods, but you will need to call them manually.

Comment: I can’t say for certain, however maybe the `move` function in pyjanitor may be helpful as well. They are just convenient wrappers around pandas functions.